# Allow for loop initialization in GCC and Clang when std={c,gnu}89?

Tags: gcc, initialization, for-loop, scope, clang

How can I enable for loop initialization when compiling in c89 or gnu89 mode using GCC and Clang?

Answer (score 0):

You can't since loop initialization is a c99 feature.
Just use gnu99 or c99